# Reading a file just by its name, without knowing its directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a project in which I am trying to read some files by only knowing their name, and not the directory in which they belong. The script file might be in the same or in a different folder than the text files (text file directories are unknown).

Comment: What if there are two files with that name?

Comment: Thank you for keeping us up to date with your coding work. Do you have a question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: what is the question, what is the problem you encounter ?

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: The following code will run for days, but you asked for it.**

```
# If you would like to limit your search to something reasonable
# replace "/" with your subdirectories.
res = os.subprocess.check_output(["find", "/", "-name", f]).decode("utf-8").split("\n")
for candidate in res:
    with open("candidate", YOUR_FLAGS):
        ... do something
```

... where `f` is your file name, and `YOUR_FLAGS` is whether you want to read it(`"r"`) or write(`"w"`), append, etc.

The reasoning behind using `os.subprocess` for this is that `os.walk` on giant file systems are not efficient. The overhead of creating a process is alleviated by the `fts` backend from `find`, and it will end up costing much less as the number of files scale.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to *search* for a file with a given name, you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and check the names match what you're looking for.  Naturally, there may be multiple files with the name you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible in one line, but you can use the os module to search for a file in all directories, for example using os.walk().

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm